# How to prevent jupyter-book from stopping build process?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, jupyter

I have the following code cell in my notebook created in `jupyterlab`:

```
import tkinter as tk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

fig = Figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 4, 9, 4, 1])

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Example")
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
canvas.draw()
button_quit = tk.Button(master=root, text="Quit", command=root.destroy)
button_quit.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
#root.mainloop()

# prevent from executing
execute=False

if execute:
    root.mainloop()
```

If I want to create a HTML book with `jupyter-book build . --all` the build process always stops while executing the notebook until I hit the quit button of the raised tk widget.

If I don't do this, I will get a timeout followed by a build error.

Is there another way to prevent from stop executing the build process than hard coding

```
# prevent from executing
execute=False

if execute:
    root.mainloop()
```

into the notebook code cell or instead waiting in front of the terminal to hit a button?

Any hint is appreciated.